# Kube: Upgrade V1.23 To V1.27 cause chart helm build problems

Tags: kubernetes, bitnami, helm

I have A kubernetes on Azure who working well in V1.22, i upgrade her and i have a problem when i build the platform service (who use a chart helm).

```
Terraform has been successfully initialized!
You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.
If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
terraform apply dev.planfile
╷
│ Warning: "use_microsoft_graph": [DEPRECATED] This field now defaults to `true` and will be removed in v1.3 of Terraform Core due to the deprecation of ADAL by Microsoft.
│ 
│ 
╵
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
null_resource.restart[0]: Destroying... [id=4241487241670744054]
null_resource.restart[0]: Destruction complete after 0s
local_file.kubeconfig: Creating...
local_file.kubeconfig: Creation complete after 0s [id=520d2cb412c868b51d8ae0eb84e1dd974b7f8d06]
helm_release.timeseries_management_service: Destroying... [id=srv-management-timeseries]
helm_release.databases_management_service: Destroying... [id=srv-management-databases]
helm_release.worksites_management_service: Destroying... [id=srv-management-worksites]
helm_release.srv_vendor_capetti: Modifying... [id=srv-vendor-capetti]
helm_release.srv_vendor_sisgeo: Modifying... [id=srv-vendor-sisgeo]
helm_release.srv_vendor_ellona: Modifying... [id=srv-vendor-ellona]
helm_release.srv_vendor_senceive: Modifying... [id=srv-vendor-senceive]
helm_release.weather_srv: Modifying... [id=weather-srv]
helm_release.srv_vendor_ftp: Modifying... [id=srv-vendor-ftp]
helm_release.srv_vendor_sites: Modifying... [id=srv-vendor-sites]
helm_release.srv_vendor_geokon: Modifying... [id=srv-vendor-geokon]
helm_release.srv_vendor_worldsensing: Modifying... [id=srv-vendor-worldsensing]
null_resource.restart[0]: Creating...
null_resource.restart[0]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "kubectl --kubeconfig=./.kube/aks-dev get po -n platform | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl --kubeconfig=./.kube/aks-dev delete pod -n platform"]
helm_release.srv_monitoring_rabbitmq: Modifying... [id=srv-monitoring-rabbitmq]
helm_release.srv_vendor_gantner: Modifying... [id=srv-vendor-gantner]
helm_release.users_management_service: Modifying... [id=srv-management-users]
helm_release.srv_vendor_campbell: Modifying... [id=srv-vendor-campbell]
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "behavior-tewapp-766b876bf5-zhctb" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "blobstorage-tewapp-6c67f47489-jlrbf" deleted
helm_release.worksites_management_service: Destruction complete after 4s
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "cmms-tewapp-59888fb86c-rjpj7" deleted
helm_release.timeseries_management_service: Destruction complete after 4s
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "connectivity-totalstation-tewapp-5b6684588-787dv" deleted
helm_release.databases_management_service: Destruction complete after 4s
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "dataintegrator-tewapp-67fff5f5b7-9c5kl" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "dataintegrator-tewapp-67fff5f5b7-q2jk8" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "jag3d-tewapp-cd5fb67dd-8lcf7" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "platform-api-tewapp-68fd65679f-btb8h" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "portal-v2-tewapp-fd85874c6-s2xhf" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "progression-tewapp-f45c77644-ntt9m" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "reprocess-tewapp-59f897b887-c22vm" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-config-toponode-tewapp-759895bf56-cn846" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-data-compute-tewapp-6b65cc66c8-c4sp7" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-data-toponode-tewapp-5d5cf54dd4-2sdqx" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-lora-tewapp-7bf8899c8-jlhvr" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-lora-vendor-a3ip-tewapp-68b56f554d-st45c" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-lora-vendor-ineosense-tewapp-6f68ffd77b-flphn" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-lora-vendor-mcf88-tewapp-5ddf549d54-sb6l6" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-management-users-tewapp-79597d4b7c-pg5th" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-monitoring-rabbitmq-28311030-vzt9v" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-monitoring-rabbitmq-28311060-bjwd6" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-monitoring-rabbitmq-28311090-2clcc" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-a3ip-tewapp-bc8f5fd8b-c5zdd" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-ackcio-tewapp-845b8b9664-cvk98" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-capetti-28310940-v7dlc" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-capetti-28311000-2wplx" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-capetti-28311060-bcwn8" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-ellona-28311075-7trtl" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-ellona-28311090-pghkt" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-ellona-28311105-jd8zq" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-geokon-28311030-4lhkd" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-geokon-28311060-p7z9q" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-geokon-28311090-2mfvr" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-gss-tewapp-86899b99fb-7w2xq" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-mcf88-tewapp-7887f5bd4d-gmvvv" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-senceive-28311030-4p2g4" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-senceive-28311060-jsbpc" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-senceive-28311090-m7xwv" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-sisgeo-28311030-ws2np" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-sisgeo-28311060-k6w88" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-sisgeo-28311090-vfp5r" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-sites-28311045-pktkq" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-sites-28311075-745g8" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-sites-28311105-hph7j" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-worldsensing-28311030-pxsrl" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-worldsensing-28311060-hm5qf" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "srv-vendor-worldsensing-28311090-rjh68" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "tewadmin-api-tewapp-78bd6db7b5-vnjs2" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "tewapi-data-tewapp-846986f687-br8mm" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "tewapi-tewapp-6db7d5f867-zrnsk" deleted
null_resource.restart[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "toponode-data-tewapp-ff6f586c5-jc7mv" deleted
helm_release.users_management_service: Still modifying... [id=srv-management-users, 10s elapsed]
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "totalstation-acceptor-tewapp-57d76c5c4b-7g98v" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "totalstation-mesh-tewapp-694fcc4fc7-wr9qj" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "uby-data-api-tewapp-7bbbb95c46-ngzrt" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "weather-srv-28310760-c29xm" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "weather-srv-28310880-vf4hh" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): pod "weather-srv-28311000-shn9j" deleted
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): Error from server (NotFound): pods "srv-management-databases-tewapp-7df58b9979-ps8hl" not found
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): Error from server (NotFound): pods "srv-management-timeseries-tewapp-7dfd849557-wmh7j" not found
null_resource.restart[0] (local-exec): Error from server (NotFound): pods "srv-management-worksites-tewapp-5f545c9d66-hfkdn" not found
helm_release.users_management_service: Modifications complete after 17s [id=srv-management-users]
╷
│ Error: local-exec provisioner error
│ 
│   with null_resource.restart[0],
│   on restart-pods.tf line 24, in resource "null_resource" "restart":
│   24:   provisioner "local-exec" {
│ 
│ Error running command 'kubectl --kubeconfig=./.kube/aks-dev get po -n
│ platform | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl
│ --kubeconfig=./.kube/aks-dev delete pod -n platform': exit status 123.
│ Output: pod "behavior-tewapp-766b876bf5-zhctb" deleted
│ pod "blobstorage-tewapp-6c67f47489-jlrbf" deleted
│ ...
│ pod "weather-srv-28311000-shn9j" deleted
│ Error from server (NotFound): pods
│ "srv-management-databases-tewapp-7df58b9979-ps8hl" not found
│ Error from server (NotFound): pods
│ "srv-management-timeseries-tewapp-7dfd849557-wmh7j" not found
│ Error from server (NotFound): pods
│ "srv-management-worksites-tewapp-5f545c9d66-hfkdn" not found
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from current release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "srv-monitoring-rabbitmq" namespace: "platform" from "": no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "batch/v1beta1"
│ ensure CRDs are installed first
│ 
│   with helm_release.srv_monitoring_rabbitmq,
│   on srv-monitoring-rabbitmq.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "srv_monitoring_rabbitmq":
│    1: resource "helm_release" "srv_monitoring_rabbitmq" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from current release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "srv-vendor-campbell" namespace: "platform" from "": no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "batch/v1beta1"
│ ensure CRDs are installed first
│ 
│   with helm_release.srv_vendor_campbell,
│   on srv-vendor-campbell.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "srv_vendor_campbell":
│    1: resource "helm_release" "srv_vendor_campbell" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from current release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "srv-vendor-capetti" namespace: "platform" from "": no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "batch/v1beta1"
│ ensure CRDs are installed first
│ 
╵...
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
make: *** [Makefile:10: apply] Error 1
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 2
```

I tryed to change:

"Versions" and "Versions" values parameters in Job/Chart.yaml
"apiVersion" in "batch/v1beta1" to "batch/v1" tewjob/templates/cronjob.yaml
"Version" "~> 2.6.0" to "~> 3.13.1" of "source = "hashicorp/helm"" in providers.tf
But nothing change (my chart is overloaded by Bitnami). Do you have an idea ?

i have many terraform config file, i have truncated the log. For Rabbit, it's just for monitoring it. By example, for a service:

```
resource "helm_release" "behavior" {
  name      = "behavior"
  namespace = kubernetes_namespace.platform.metadata.0.name
  chart     = local.tewapp_chart_path

  set {
    name  = "chart_hash"
    value = local.tewapp_chart_hash
  }

  values = [file("behavior-${local.env}.yaml"), <<-EOT
  extraEnvVars:
    - name: "ConnectionStrings__MSSQL" 
      value: "Data Source=mssql1.data;Initial Catalog=testdb;User=${data.terraform_remote_state.data.outputs.mssql1_user};Password=${data.terraform_remote_state.data.outputs.mssql1_pass}"
    - name: "ConnectionStrings__rabbitmq"
      value: "amqp://${data.terraform_remote_state.data.outputs.rabbitmq_user}:${data.terraform_remote_state.data.outputs.rabbitmq_admin_pass}@rabbitmq.data"
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 5m
      memory: 501Mi
    limits:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 1000Mi
  EOT
  ]

  set {
    name  = "image.tag"
    value = local.behavior_tag
  }

  set {
    name  = "name"
    value = "behavior"
  }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's because i have update kube version before redirect API.
For corrct it i have to delete all cronJobs and recreate them:

1. kubectl get secret -n platform | awk '/srv-vendor-MyJob1.v/{print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete secret -n platform
2. kubectl delete -n platform cronjob srv-vendor-MyJob1

For all jobs

And rebuild